# IIS Web.config Redirect with query to subdomain

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am looking to make a redirect on URLs with a specific search query to go to a sub domain like below:

Original: 
https://example.com/property.php?id=9999

New:
https://search.example.com/property/9999

I tried this (second rule):

```html
<rewrite>
      <rules>
                  
          <rule name="Sitemap Re-direct" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="sitemap.xml" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="sitemap" appendQueryString="false"/>
          </rule>
                                
          <rule name="RewriteToSearch">
                <match url="^search/property.php?id=([0-9]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://search.sourced.co/property/{R:1}/" />
          </rule>
                                
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But it did not work?

Thanks!

Comment: Tell me why you use that value of `url` in `match` tag please.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you solve this ?